# dynamiclink not working in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to add a link to my column value in jqgrid. However its not working.

```js
function urlTemplate() {
    return ({formatter:'dynamicLink',formatoptions:{url: genUrl, target:"_blank"},
    sorttype:"link", searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}});
}
```

```js
function genUrl(cellValue, rowId, rowData){
    return ("{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}" + rowData.caseId);
}
```

```js
{name:'caseId',index:'caseId', width:40,hidden: true},
{name:'caseNumber',index:'CaseNumber', width:40,template: urlTemplate()},
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? `dynamicLink` is not the part of jqGrid. It can be loaded from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js). If you use free jqGrid, then you can use `formatter: "showlink"` because of [the enhancements](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/improvement-of-formatter:-%22showlink%22) implemented in free jqGrid.

Comment: In any way `sorttype:"link"` is wrong. It's unclear for me too why you define `urlTemplate` as function and call it as `template: urlTemplate()`. If you would use `formatter: "showlink"` of free jqGrid then you will have to change  the options of `formatoptions`. It has `baseLinkUrl` for example instead of `url`. It can be defined as function, but with other parameters (one `options` parameters, which has `rowData` property).

Comment: i am using 4.6 version. I am new to JS, so just learning

Comment: its not working with showlink also.

Comment: *What* is not working with showlink (which code you use now)? Which version and from which fork of jqGrid you use now? I wrote you that the exchanged features of the showlink formatter exist only in free jqGrid fork (and not in jqGrid 4.6). It's better if you would prepare the demo (in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for example). Then I (or somebody else) could modify the demo to fix the problem.

Comment: {name:'caseId',index:'caseId', hidden: true},
{name:'caseNumber',index:'CaseNumber', formatter: 'showLink',formatoptions: {baseLinkUrl: function (rowData) {return "/" + encodeURIComponent(rowData.caseId);},
idName: 'caseId'

With this change also, not getting the hyperlink

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use now?** In any way it's wrong code! If you use jqGrid 4.6 then it's wrong because `baseLinkUrl` can be a function. If you use free jqGrid 4.13.3 then it's wrong because the function should be `baseLinkUrl: function (options) { return "/" + encodeURIComponent(options.rowData.caseId); }`

Comment: Yes, I tried with the same function as well.

Comment: I have 2 columns in JQGrid. One is caseId and the other is case number. So for every case number a link should be shown. Clicking on the case should redirect to the case taking the id from caseId. Now after modifying my code, I am getting the link but it is taking the link as of my page. I want to give a different link.

Comment: Sorry, but you don't answer on questions which I ask you (see my above comments). Moreover you write very unclear statements like "I am getting the link but it is taking the link as of my page. I want to give a different link.". It would be much better if you would include **the exact** input data like `{"caseId": 123, "caseNumber": "xyz"}` and **the link generated in the cell** like `<a href="https://google.com?q=123">xyz</a>` and include the link (`<a>`) which you expect to have. I suggested you to create JSFiddle demo. It would speed up finding the solution and it'll save our time.

Comment: Input that I get from my SOQL query is :  `{"caseid":"500e00000092PqQAAU","caseNumber":"00270785","checklistBar":"&lt;a href=&quot;#progress-0&quot; target=&quot;0%&quot;&gt; &lt;/a&gt;","contactId":"003a000001ylUcwAAE","contactName":"Stephanie Holland","createdDate":1460536587000}`

In my JQGrid, Id is one column and casenumber is another. casenumber should have hyperlink which should redirect to the case with the Id as caseId. I think this is clear. Creating JSFiddle in itself is a big task for me .

Comment: You should place **all information related the question in the text of the question**. You should click on "edit" link below your question and **modify** your text. You will have much better possibilities to format the code. The goal of stackoverflow is not helping the person, who ask the question. The goal is sharing *common question*, which could help other people. Thus you should reread your question from the point of view a new person. Your question should contain all information important for understanding the problem.